# Ajax form not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Somehow my form is not working. Anyone knows why?
Seems like ajax is not kicking in at all, because the action kicking in is data.php and not data_ajax.php, which I should see if ajax is working.

**EDIT**

Changed the HTML to what it actually looks like, though it should be the same result.

HTML

```
<div id="hidden_slidersize"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
if ($('body').width() >= 960) {
var sizeOfSlider = 500;
} else {
var sizeOfSlider = ($('body').width())/2;
}
$('#hidden_slidersize').html('<form id="dataform" method="post" name="hiddentrick_form" action="data.php"><fieldset><input id="hiddentrick" name="hiddentrick" type="hidden" value="' + sizeOfSlider + '" /><input class="datasubmit" type="submit" value="senddata" /></fieldset></form>');
});
</script>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var form = $('form#dataform');

      form.submit(function () { 

    $.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: 'data_ajax.php',  
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType:'html',  
      success: function(data) {alert('yes');},
      error: function(data) {
      //AJAX request not completed
      alert('no');
      }
    });  
    return false;  

      });
});
```

Comment: There must be something wrong either 1- in `data_ajax.php` or 2- somewhere else in your script. Exact copy-paste (replaced `data_ajax.php` URI) works: http://jsfiddle.net/r9Cj7/

Comment: How do you submit the form? Is there a button to click?

Comment: Right now there's a submit button, though my plan is to make it automatic when it works.
the data_ajax.php-file doesn't exist. I've made this so that I can make sure ajax is kicking in and I will get an alert 'no' back. But right now I'm getting - can't find data.php. That will say, ajax is not working.

Comment: On the first line of **data_ajax.php** file, put in **exit("Got here")** and then **alert** that result from the AJAX. If you receive that message, it means the AJAX works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method because your content is loaded dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on('submit', 'form#dataform', function () { 

    $.ajax({  
      type: 'POST',  
      url: 'data_ajax.php',  
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType:'html',  
      success: function(data) {alert('yes');},
      error: function(data) {
      //AJAX request not completed
      alert('no');
      }
    });  
    return false;  

      });
});
```

Comment: This one sounds more promising.

Comment: That works great! Thanks a lot :) Unfortunatly I don't have reputation enough to vote up your response.

Comment: No but I think you can put 'best answer'.